# whats wrong with this code in python

Tags: python

hi im trying to figure out why this isn´t working

```
def fun():
   a = [1,4]
   b = [2,5]
   c = [3,6]
   return a,b,c
```

I want to print `a`, `b` and `c` but calling `print(x)`, `print(y)` and `print(z)`

```
for x,y,z in fun():
   print(x)
```

The only thing I get is

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Answer (score 5):

You can either do this:

```
def fun():
   a = [1,4]
   b = [2,5]
   c = [3,6]
   return a,b,c

for item in fun():
    print(item)
```

Or:

```
x,y,z = fun()
print(x)
```

You cannot iterate through the return value of the function the way you are doing it right now.

Edit:

The problem with doing

```
for x,y,z in fun():
```

is that `fun()` is equal to `([1,4], [2,5], [3,6])`. That means that there is no `z` value when you iterate through that tuple. So if you wanted to do it that way, you could do:

```
for x,y in fun():
   print(x,y)
```

although you wouldn't be printing the lists but iterating over each item in the lists and printing the items.

Edit credit: [Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6656050/jeremy-kahan)'s comment.

Comment: actually for x,y in fun():
   print(x, y) works for me. Part of the issue is that the return is a set of 3 pairs, not two triples.

Comment: Oh interesting, I hadn't thought about it that way. So looks like doing that just replaces fun() by ([1,4], [2,5], [3,6]) and iterates over that tuple then?

Comment: Yea, I think so. Thanks for the shout out in the edit.